# Numeros por teclado

Tags: c#

Ingresar siete numeros por teclado , imprimir el mayor, el menor y la cantidad de numeros que se ingresaron

```
Console.WriteLine("Ejercicio 4");
        int suma,f
        for (x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero");

        }
```

Mi duda es que no se como seguir

Comment: Bienvenido.. ¿cuál es tu duda?

Comment: si estas pidiendo que se ingresen 7 numeros para que necesitas que se informe la cantidad de ingresados? ya la conoces son 7

Answer (score 0):

Si usas una lista es simple de definir

```
List<int> nroList = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine("Ejercicio 4");

for (x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero {0}:", i);
    int nro = Convert.Toint32(Console.ReadLine());

    nroList.Add(nro);
}

Console.WriteLine("Valor Minimo: {0}", nroList.Min());
Console.WriteLine("Valor Maximo: {0}", nroList.Max());
```

Con los metodos `Max()` y `Min()` de linq puede obtener el valor de una lista de valores

[Enumerable.Max Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8)